# What is the error the next line is talking about?

Tags: r

```
test <- data.frame(SP = scaled$SP)
myprediction <- compute(x=mod1, covariate=test)
Error in `[.data.frame`(newdata, , object$model.list$variables) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I get that error in the console and cant figure out what column it's talking about

Comment: What package is the `compute` function from? Also can you provide the data that builds the `test` data frame?

Comment: Can you try it with `compute(x=mod1, covariate=test$SP)`?